# Symmetries of irregular simplices

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, symmetry

On the wikipedia page of [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Isometries_of_irregular_tetrahedra), there is a list of eight symmetry groups for a (possibly irregular) $3$-simplex (with unmarked faces).  There is also a list on the page of [5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell#Irregular_5-cell) but doesn't seem complete.

This seems elementary, but I can not find a source to cite.  Also, is there already a general classification for symmetry groups of unmarked (possibly irreglar) d-simplices (or an algorithm for enumerating it)?

I believe this is equivalent to asking about the symmetry of edge-colored complete graphs.  I find a lot of literature on those with transitive groups, but not general cases.

Comment: As a help for others to find an answer: this seems an interesting and perfectly well-defined question; to paraphrase: the OP is asking for citable sources on *what are all the possible isomorphism types of of the (necessarily finite) subgroups which arise as the set-wise stabiliser, inside the full [Euclidean group $E(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group), of a specified geometric realization of a simplicial complex in $\mathbb{R}^n$*, the realization being arbitrary (except, perhaps, being piecewise-linear, but even that needn't be said, I think). There are indeed [...]

Comment: [...] many such isomorphism groups, starting from the trivial group (which arises for most 'irregular' geometric realizations) all the way to the symmetric  group $\mathrm{Sym}(n)$. The OP also points out that any such geometric realization defines an inclusion of groups of the relevant symmetryi group into the autormorphism group of a **$k$-colored graph** in the sense of e.g. [Mariusz Grech, Andrzej Kisielewicz: *All totally symmetric colored graphs*. arXiv:1201.4464v1]. The OP seems right in that  it is not easy to read-off an answer to the question from the literature, in particular [...]

Comment: [...] op. cit. has a general title, yet is not sufficient by itself to answer this question. The *most difficult part of the question (to me) seems to rigorously show that the question even **can** be reduced to graph theory; it is not clear that **all** the relevant graph-theoretic symmetries can be realized by a Euclidean symmetry.* It seems that if someone likes to get into this question, then carefully working out the connection between coloring-preserving automorphisms of complete graphs and simplex-realization-preserving Euclidean symmetries is the most important step towards an answer.

Comment: FYI, I consulted with the wikipedia editor.  He used a software to calculate the subgroups of the tetrahedral group.  He also mentioned Conway's book "the symmetries of things".  There is a poset for the octahedral group, from which one can extract a poset for the tetrahedral group (if he manages to understand the notation system).

Comment: But all these are only for dimension 3 and are not direct reference for what I'm asking.